# Send model to Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fuelux

I would like to create tree in my mvc view using [Fuelux](http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/) jquery plugin. To use this plugin I have to send data to plugin with next code:

> $('#MyTree').tree({ dataSource: dataSource })

I don't have any idea how to send my model object in view as parameter to plugin. What structure data must have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to conver you model to Json and use the converted object as a datasource:

```
<script>
$(dcoument).ready(function(){

var datasource = @ViewBag.JsonModel;
$('#MyTree').tree({ dataSource: dataSource });

});
</script>
```

Now you need to populate ViewBag.JsonModel in the action:

```
public ViewResult YourActionName()
{
 // your logic on getting model
ViewBag.JsonModel = //convert model to json using jsonserializer
}
```

Here is tree plugin example:

```
 // INITIALIZING TREE
var treeDataSource = new TreeDataSource({
data: [
{ name: 'Test Folder 1', type: 'folder', additionalParameters: { id: 'F1' } },
{ name: 'Test Folder 2', type: 'folder', additionalParameters: { id: 'F2' } },
{ name: 'Test Item 1', type: 'item', additionalParameters: { id: 'I1' } },
{ name: 'Test Item 2', type: 'item', additionalParameters: { id: 'I2' } }
],
delay: 400
});
$('#MyTree').tree({dataSource: treeDataSource});
```

Comment: Which properties my model must have ? there is not any information in plugin documentation about it.

Comment: Look i've added tree example to my response

Comment: I've just try your solution. I've getting error "Unable to get property 'fn' of undefined or null reference". maybe some additional properties are reqired in json data?

Comment: Here is the example page link http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/#tree. It contains worling example of the Tree.js, have a look at the source code (I prefer firebug)